# Как добавить в исключение php-скрипта директорию

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть скрипт

```
<?php
$to="info@info.ru";
$subj="info.ru: WARNING! MODIFY FILES";
$from="info.ru";
$url="http://info.ru";
$listfile="1txt.txt";
$list_file="2txt.txt";

GLOBAL $no_check,$total_size,$files,$folders;

$no_check=array("index1.html","1txt.txt","2txt.txt","../../public_html/temp");
$root_dir="../../public_html";
$total_size=$files=$folders=0;
$dir=opendir($root_dir);
scan_dir($root_dir);

function scan_dir($dirname){
    GLOBAL $arr;

    $dir=opendir($dirname);
    while(($file=readdir($dir))!==false){
        if($file!="."&&$file!=".."){
            if(is_file($dirname."/".$file)){
                if(!in_array($file,$GLOBALS['no_check'])){
                    $arr[]=str_replace($root_dir,"../",$dirname)."/".$file." &nbsp;***&nbsp; ВРЕМЯ ОБРАЩЕНИЯ К ФАЙЛУ: ".date("d.m.y H:i:s",filemtime($dirname."/".$file))." &nbsp;***&nbsp; РАЗМЕР В БАЙТАХ: ".filesize($dirname."/".$file);
                }
                $GLOBALS['files']++;
                $GLOBALS['total_size']+=filesize($dirname."/".$file);
            }
            if(is_dir($dirname."/".$file)){
                $arr[]=$dirname."/".$file;
                $GLOBALS['folders']++;
                scan_dir($dirname."/".$file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}

$list=fopen($listfile,"r+");
if($list AND filesize($listfile)>0){
    $file=fopen($listfile,"r");
    $bufer=fread($file,filesize($listfile));
    fclose($file);
    $arr1=unserialize($bufer);
    $arr2=array_diff($arr,$arr1);
    $arr3=array_diff($arr1,$arr);
    if((count($arr2)+count($arr3))==0){
        if($id==1)
            echo " Изменений файлов со времени последнего сканирования не обнаружено<br>";
    }else{
        $mess1="<span style='font-family:courier new;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'>Новые и измененные файлы</span><br /><br />\n";
        if($id==1)
            $mess1.="<br />";
        foreach($arr2 as $val){
            $list_links=$val;
            $val1=substr($val,1);
            if(substr($val1,0,1)==".")
                $val1=substr($val1,1);
            if(substr($val1,0,1)==".")
                $val1=substr($val1,1);
            $val1=str_replace($root_dir,"",$val);
            $val2=str_replace($root_dir,"",$val);
            $val1="<a href=$url$val1 target=_blank>".$val1."</a><br><br>";
            $mess1=$mess1."$val1 \n";
            $links.=$list_links."\n";
        }
        $mess2="<br />____________________________________________________________<br /><br />\n\n<span style='font-family:courier new;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'>Удаленные файлы и файлы измененные ранее</span><br /><br />\n";
        foreach($arr3 as $val){
            $mess2=$mess2."$val <br><br>\n";
        }
        $mess=$mess1.$mess2;
        if(((1024*1024)>$total_size)&&($total_size>1024))
            $size=(round($total_size/1024))." KИЛОБАЙТ";
        elseif($total_size>(1024*1024))
            $size=(round($total_size/1024/1024))." MЕГАБАЙТ";
        $mess.="<br />____________________________________________________________<br /><br />\n<span style='font-family:courier new;font-size:1.2em;'>ОБЩИЙ ОБЪЕМ ФАЙЛОВ: $size ($total_size БАЙТ), ВСЕГО ФАЙЛОВ: $files, ПАПОК: $folders</span>";
        if($id==1)
            echo $mess;
        $subj=convert_cyr_string(stripslashes($subj),w,k);
        $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers.="From: $from\n";
        $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251";
        mail($to,$subj,$mess,$headers);
        $str=serialize($arr);
        $file=fopen($listfile,"w");
        fwrite($file,$str);
        fclose($file);
        $file_list_links=fopen($list_file,"w");
        fwrite($file_list_links,$links);
        fclose($file_list_links);
    }
}else{
    $str=serialize($arr);
    $file=fopen($listfile,"w");
    fwrite($file,$str);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

который сканирует файловую систему ubuntu на наличие\отсутствие изменений в файлах, наличие посторонних (новых) файлов.
В массиве **$no_check** перечислены файлы, исключенные из сканирования. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в исключение целую директорию (и с файлами в ней, и пустую)?

Comment: и где ваш код сканирования?

Comment: А зачем Вам целый код? Вопрос лишь: "как добавить в исключение целую директорию, т.е., как указать в массиве нечто такое, чтобы скрипт считал это нечто за папку, а не за файл" п.с. Если такое возможно вообще.

Comment: @andry добавьте в массив название директории и проверяйте директория это или нет. Код нужен для [минимально воспроизводимого примера и следовательно для более качественных ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: указал целиком, разминимизировал как смог, чтобы быстро.

Comment: бгг. а какой смысл минимизации вашей? :)

Comment: есть у вас проверка `is_dir($dirname)` вот в там и проверьте, что эта `$dirname` не попадает в массив  исключений.

Comment: Я не вижу, где у вас эта переменная `$no_check` в коде используется. Вижу только ее инициализацию и объявление глобальной

Comment: 1. Функция `scan_dir` не знает переменную `$root_dir`. 2. Для сравнения используется `&&`. 3. `global` зло.

Comment: К сожалению, я не смог понять, о чем здесь участники говорили. Несколько примеров и все ***отчасти***. Плюс какие-то переменные не найдены... Я запутался. Скрипт вроде как рабочий-проверен не одним месяцем. Мне просто нужно было как-нибудь запихнуть в массив директорию, дабы добавить ее в исключения.